# Using spring-rabbit, spring-amqp. How to set thread-name of listener thread started using SimpleMessageListenerContainer.start()

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

Using SimpleMessageListenerContainer.start() to start listener threads in client machine to listen for messages from RabbitMQ.    All listener threads have name as SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 .   Is there a way user can provide/set name of listener-thread (to help troubleshooting issue by seeing threadname and relating part of code that this thread belongs to)

Following is summary of my current implementation ---

I am using xml file with following tags to define connection factory, queue, binding etc.  For example, XML tags used are Rabbit:queues , Rabbit:queue-arguments , Rabbit:direct-exchange , Rabbit:topic-exchange, Rabbit:bindings, rabbit:binding , Rabbit:Admin (with ConnectionFactory)

Following is code snippet to start listener---

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container= new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(messagingTopology.getConnectionFactory());
container.setQueueNames(new String[] { messagingTopology.getQueue().getName() });
MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener); 
container.setMessageListener(adapter); 
container.start();
```

Comment: One workaround is to set threadname (only once by checking some state variable) in MessagePostProcessor.postProcessMessage that gets called just before onMessage.   Downside is that name will be set only when first message will be received... 
Note:    We are using xml with following tags to define connection factory, queue, binding etc.

Rabbit:Queues , Rabbit:queue-arguments , • Rabbit:DIRECTExchange , Rabbit:TOPICExchange, Rabbit:binding , Rabbit:Admin [[[ ConnectionFactory]]]

Comment: Following is sample code that I am currently using to start listener.

SimpleMessageListenerContainer container=  new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(); 
container.setConnectionFactory(messagingTopology.getConnectionFactory());
container.setQueueNames(new String[] { messagingTopology.getQueue().getName() });
container.setMessageListener(adapter);

container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(loggingMessagingPostProcessor);
  container.start();
container.start();                                            Considering above code how thread name can be set in listener while starting listener?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it doesn't render well; it's better to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `taskExecutor` (`task-executor` in XML) property on the listener container. The thread name is based on the executor's bean name so use a different one for each container.

Comment: With recent versions of the framework (2.0 or later) the threads are automatically named after the container bean name or the `@RabbitListener` `id` attribute.

Comment: Regarding taskExecutor ,  there are some considerations listed on following java doc ,  hence I feel it may have cause some impact in long term...  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#setTaskExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-

Comment: Regarding 2nd approach(2.0 or later) of naming via "container bean name" --- in our common messaging framework, we get respective listener instances from  our application-components and create as new instance as follows...  How this code can be updated to leverage container's bean-name approach ?   MessageListenerAdapter  adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener);      SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();    container.setConnectionFactory(messagingTopology.getConnectionFactory()); container.setMessageListener(adapter); container.start();

Comment: SimpleMessageListenerContainer has various set* apis.   A setter api to set name of listener-thread can be worth.

Comment: The javadoc you referenced is JMS, not RabbitMQ. You should not put code in comments; it doesn't render well; it's better to edit the question and comment that you have done so. If you are not using Spring to manage your containers, you can simply `setListenerId("myId")` and the threads will be named `myId-0` etc. For versions before 1.7.13, 2.0.12 and 2.1.5 use `setBeanName()`. But it's best to upgrade to the latest version in each generation.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Edited question with code.      We have a plan for upgrading spring-amqp, spring-rabbit (from version is 1.6.7). That will need other spring framework jars upgrade also hence it is going to take some time...    
       Meanwhile I need some way of setting thread-name in version 1.6.7       You mentioned that for versions before 1.7.13 setBeanName() can be used... I will try that and will share the result

Comment: Naming the thread based on the `beanName` was added in 1.6.0. The current 1.6.x release is 1.6.11, but you should really upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Yes, team has plan of upgrade... it will take some time to upgrade along with latest spring framework jars...   Meanwhile as per your comment, since since naming of thread based on beanName was added in 1.6.0 hence I am going to try that out in my 1.6.7 version and share the result